# Javascript. Compare UNIX timestamps

Tags: javascript

I got two timestamps in unix format and I need to find a way to compare them and to find out which one is the newest (closest to present date).

The two timestamps are:

- 1299925246
- 1300526796

Is there a simple way of doing this in Javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is expressed as the number of seconds elapsed since January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

Comparison is therefore straightforward: in your example, the second timestamp (`1300526796`) is the newest, because `1300526796` (March 19th, 2011, 09:26:36 UTC) is greater than `1299925246` (March 12th, 2011, 10:20:46 UTC).

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of future timestamps?

Comment: @Yi Jiang, if I understand your comment correctly, `Math.abs(timestamp - now)` will return the number of seconds between `timestamp` (be it in the future or not) and `now`.

Comment: The date object in javascript counts the milliseconds since the unix epoc, so just multiply a unix timestamp by 1000 to get a javascript time, or divide a javascript timestamp by 1000 to get a unix timestamp. In javascript you get an object with the current time by doing `new Date()`

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered the same issue, but with multiple timestamps, like so:

```
1356036198452 
1356039026690
1356039067568
1356035166411
```

In my case, there could be anywhere from 1 to 100 timestamps available.

So the quickest way to get to the "newest" date (in my opinion) would be to do this:

```
var newestDate = Math.max(1356036198452,1356039026690,1356039067568,1356035166411);
alert(newestDate);
```

Hope that helps someone out there in the real world.